# How to "inflate" or "grow" a rectangle in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Does Qt have a built-in way to inflate or grow a rectangle? Like .NET's [`Rectangle.Inflate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.inflate.aspx) or Java's [`Rectangle.grow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#grow%28int,%20int%29)... or do I have to implement my own? I've looked through the docs and couldn't find one but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be an [`adjust`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#adjust) function that comes closest to what you want. You could easily use it to "inflate" a rectangle:

```
rect.adjust(-dx, -dy, dx, dy);
```

where `dx` and `dy` are the amounts you want to inflate in the x and y directions.

Comment: This seems about the best. Thanks.